# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to run a `node seed.js` file in the terminal to connect my project the mongodb backend server, but keep receiving the following error:

```
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017',
  stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017\n' +
    '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/caseydzuong/Desktop/movierama/vidly-api-node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:503:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/caseydzuong/Desktop/movierama/vidly-api-node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:326:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/caseydzuong/Desktop/movierama/vidly-api-node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    (node:3807) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:3807) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've already tried whitelisting my IP address by adding '0.0.0.0/0' to the whitelist; it didn't work. What else can I do?

Here's the seed.js file:

> const { Genre } = require("./models/genre"); const { Movie } =
> require("./models/movie"); const mongoose = require("mongoose"); const
> config = require("config");
>
> const data = [   {
> name: "Comedy",
> movies: [
> { title: "Airplane", numberInStock: 5, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "The Hangover", numberInStock: 10, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "Wedding Crashers", numberInStock: 15, dailyRentalRate: 2 }
> ]   },   {
> name: "Action",
> movies: [
> { title: "Die Hard", numberInStock: 5, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "Terminator", numberInStock: 10, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "The Avengers", numberInStock: 15, dailyRentalRate: 2 }
> ]   },   {
> name: "Romance",
> movies: [
> { title: "The Notebook", numberInStock: 5, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "When Harry Met Sally", numberInStock: 10, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "Pretty Woman", numberInStock: 15, dailyRentalRate: 2 }
> ]   },   {
> name: "Thriller",
> movies: [
> { title: "The Sixth Sense", numberInStock: 5, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "Gone Girl", numberInStock: 10, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
> { title: "The Others", numberInStock: 15, dailyRentalRate: 2 }
> ]   } ];
>
> async function seed() {   await mongoose.connect(config.get("db"));
>
> await Movie.deleteMany({});   await Genre.deleteMany({});
>
> for (let genre of data) {
> const { _id: genreId } = await new Genre({ name: genre.name }).save();
> const movies = genre.movies.map(movie => ({
> ...movie,
> genre: { _id: genreId, name: genre.name }
> }));
> await Movie.insertMany(movies);   }
>
> mongoose.disconnect();
>
> console.info("Done!"); }
>
> seed();

Comment: Adding your `seed.js` file code would help to answer your question better.

Comment: Editted, thanks for looking! Hope you can help :)

Comment: Is `mongodb` server running at the same default port in your local machine (`localhost:27017`)?

Comment: No, the mongodb server isn't running, I don't think. If you have specific instructions on how I can check, I can check for you :)

Comment: If it's not running in your local then please start the server or change the host to remote address in case if it's running in remote machine. Please check `mongo` [CLI commands as per docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#start-the-mongo-shell-and-connect-to-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

The error seems self explanatory

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
[Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

Check if `mongodb` server is running in  your `local` at port `27017`.

(or)

Change the `host` and `port` details accordingly if it's running in other **remote machine**. For [your reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#start-the-mongo-shell-and-connect-to-mongodb).